# Passing javascript array to a java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, arrays, servlets

I have an array that gets populated and then as I send it my servlet receives it as null.

```
var allIcons = new Array();
$('.icon').each(function(index){
  allIcons.push($(this).find('.iconName').html());
});
```

That seems to be filling up the array with the appropriate fields

I am then passing it to my servlet using

```
$.ajax({
   "dataType" : 'json',
   "type": 'GET',
   "url" : 'update'
   "data" :{
      "allIcons" : allIcons
   }, "success": function(json){alert("alert");}});
```

My servlet is then attempting to read it but always gets back null

```
if(request.getParamtersValues("allIcons").length > 0) {/*do something*/}
```

request.getParamterValues() should return a String[]

In addition I know my servlet is able to receive data since this is in addition to some other code. 
Thanks 
-Tommy

Comment: do a `request.getParameterNames()` and see what you got there first.

Comment: sounds like js array `allIcons` don't have any data in it.

Comment: Well.... yes, the request.getParameterNames() returned me "allIcons[]" where I was looking for "allIcons" without the brackets. So, if you are looking for an array coming from JS to a servlet be sure to use the right parameters and put '[]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request.getParameterNames() returned me "allIcons[]" where I was looking for "allIcons" without the brackets. So, if you are looking for an array coming from JS to a servlet be sure to use the right parameters. Be sure to add your braces. "[]"

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   dataType : 'json',
   type: 'GET',
   url : 'update'
   data :{
      "allIcons" : allIcons
   }, success: function(data){alert("alert");}});
```

Comment: That works for the jquery/ajax side but on the servlet side I was having trouble finding the name of what was being passed. As I commented (with the answer) I needed the braces at the end.